# find correct download javax.media.jai

Tags: java

I need to use:

```
import javax.media.jai.PerspectiveTransform;
import javax.media.jai.WarpPerspective;
```

I found so many topics about getting the javax.media framework.
Most lead to this soultion:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#7372-jmf-2.1.1e-oth-JPR

Which has a download older then the big bang, missing those the classes i need.

Does someone know where i can download what i need?

Here is one of the javadocs in case it helps:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/WarpPerspective.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check it here once [jai jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjaicorejar.htm)